# getting data from two table based on third table information - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i have three tables one has master information, another one has changes compared to the master fields. both has same fields.
third table has the data of what set of records belongs to a particular type.
my query should select the fields of a particular type from third table. then it should go the changes table and get the changed records of the type and then select remaining records from the master table.

can any one help me...i am new to data base designing and to MYSQL i need to design DB.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just spit out answers, take a look at foreign keys and joins.

If you have MasterTable, ChangeTable and DataTable, and you're querying for User, if you put UserId as a field in each table, then you could do a join on that user id, and this would allow you to get all your records without creating multiple queries.

Comment: Thanks for the response....the way you are telling will work to get all the records based on user id but in this case i need to check the change table for the records present in there and then check the remaining id's (records for that id) from the master table...so here the critical part for me is how to differenciate what it should look in the master.....is it possible to do all this in one query?...i home i am confusing...thanks

Comment: basically what i want is in the final results, the records i got from the master table should be updated with the records i got from the changes table according to the id.